# Android customize foreground service notification

Tags: android, android-service

How to customize foreground service notification?
I tried:

```
private void startForegoundService() {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.custom_notification);
    Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContent(remoteViews);

    startForeground(mforegroundNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Where R.layout.custom_notification is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/notification_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7777"
    android:padding="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_enable_alarm"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="Eye"
        android:src="@drawable/action_enable_alarm" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't have any effect. I need customize exactly foreground service notification. Not just "fake" notification for service.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem is fixed by adding small icon value. Full code:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.custom_small_icon).setContent(remoteViews);
```

Comment: Why `setSmallIcon()` controls visibility of custom content?

Comment: @Nasib Hi! I didn't test it on Android Pie

Comment: @XIII-th I don't know why, but I just found this answer and used `setSmallIcon()` and it fixed the problem for me too. Thanks OP.

Comment: need help here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64984730/custom-notification-is-not-displaying-using-fcm